# Shiny creating a reactive legend

Tags: r, shiny, legend

I am following a solution given in [R shiny Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (8): y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53163119/r-shiny-aesthetics-must-be-either-length-1-or-the-same-as-the-data-8-y) for that annoying problem which I have happily fixed.

The next issue I want to solve is that I want my plot to have a reactive legend - I only want the legend to display what's actually chosen and on the plot

I also want to set the colours of the lines to the ones I want. And finally I want to make sure the legend is always in the order that I specify

Here is a reproducible example (the commented out code is my attempt at solving my own issues.

As you can see, the commented out section is how I've tried to get the legend and colours I want:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)

time <- seq(-9, 60, 1)
var1 <- rnorm(70, 35, 2)
var2 <- rnorm(70, 50, 2)
var3 <- rnorm(70, 24, 2)
var4 <- rnorm(70, 17, 2)

data <- data.frame(time = time, 
                   var1 = var1, 
                   var2 = var2,
                   var3 = var3,
                   var4 = var4)

datamelt <- melt(data, "time")

p <- ggplot(datamelt, aes(x = time, y = value, color = variable)) +
  # scale_color_manual(values = c(
  # 'first' = 'red',
  # 'second' = 'blue',
  #   'third' = 'green',
  #   'fourth' = 'orange'
  #   ),
  # breaks = c("first", "second", "third", "fourth")) +
  #  labs(color = 'Legend') +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  labs(title = 'it means nothing',
       subtitle = 'these are made up data') +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name ="a y variable", breaks = seq(-9, 60, 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "yep an x variable", 
                     breaks = seq(0, 60, 5), labels = comma) + geom_blank()


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("trying to make this work"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("whichone", "Choose something:", 
                         choiceNames = c("first", 
                                         "second", 
                                         "third",
                                         "fourth"), 
                         choiceValues = c("var1", 
                                          "var2",
                                          "var3",
                                          "var4"))
    ),
    ###the plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      data_filtered <- datamelt %>% filter(variable %in% input$whichone)
      p + geom_line(data = data_filtered)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because `ggplot` uses all the factor levels, which stay in place when you filter. So you need to drop these levels first.

Secondly, you are generating the plot statically with all the levels. So you need to update the data in teh plto as well to let `ggplot` know which levels to show in the legend. Putting that together you can use the following:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ## 1. drop unused levels from teh filtered database
      data_filtered <- datamelt %>% filter(variable %in% input$whichone) %>%
          droplevels()
      ## 2. tell ggplot to update the data
      p %+% data_filtered + geom_line()
   })
}
```

*Note.* This approach has the nasty (?) side effect, that if you do not select any data to show you see only an empty canvas. This can be also remedied, but would require some change in your code logic (basically moving the construction of the `ggplot` inside the `renderPlot`)

---

**Screenshots**
[image: One Selected]
[image: Two Selected]
[image: Three Selected]

Comment: Thanks for this. This works but the legend still displays all 4 variables (with names var1, var2 etc) even when they are not selected. And, when I remove the bit commented out to try and change the legend names and the colours I get the following error: "Warning: Removed 70 rows containing missing values (geom_path)." I think i'm really missing some understanding in how R uses the scale_colour_manual() to make a legend and how this can be combined with Shiny's reactivity. What online resources would you suggest to get some intuition?

Comment: Hm, I don't get the same behaviour. I attach some screenshots showing that the legend is updated. The principle is easy: in your render function make sure that the data you are passing to `ggplot` has only the levels you want to show. Then the legend is correct. Start with the built in legend and then try to change to custom colors.

Comment: That's really weird. Thanks i'll make sure to copy + paste all the code exactly as here and see if it works the same.

Comment: Just copy + pasted it all in, it worked exactly like your screenshots, thank you for this :)